# Converting string into html hyperlinks in Laravel

Tags: php, regex, laravel, preg-replace

I'm using this code to hyperlink links from posts in Laravel:

```
{!! preg_replace('@(http(s)?)?(://)?(([a-zA-Z])([-\w]+\.)+([^\s\.]+[^\s]*)+[^,.\s])@', '<a href="http$2://$4" target="_blank" title="$0">$0</a>', nl2br(e($post))) !!}
```

But if I type this:

Hello.

How are you?

I'm getting this weird link "Hello. /> How are you?".

What should I do? I don't know how to work with regex. I want to hyperlink only strings that starts with http://, https://, www., not links like anyword.anydomain.

Comment: Start your pattern with a lookahead: `\b(?=https?://|www.)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I have found is this library: https://github.com/misd-service-development/php-linkify

```
$linkify = new \Misd\Linkify\Linkify();
$text = 'This is my text containing a link to www.example.com.';
echo $linkify->process($text);
```

Would output:

This is my text containing a link to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).